# How can I pass GET parameters in outputLink value?

Tags: jsp, jsf, hyperlink, http-request-parameters

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
<h:outputLink id="cmdlink" value="newtopic.jsp?id=<%=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("parent"))%>">
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do not ever use *scriptlets*. It only leads you into the wrong direction as to solving the particular functional requirement.

Answer (score 3):

try something like this

```
<h:outputLink id="cmdlink" value="newtopic.jsp">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{param['parent']}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

about the `%3F` that you have its actually a `?` being replaced with `%3F`

Comment: I tried your code, and it will go on page /newtopic.jsp?%3Fid=         ... what's wrong? :/

Comment: you mean `/newtopic.jsp?%3Fid=valueOfParent` ? is it working , is there a difference if you manually enter `/newtopic.jsp?%3Fid=valueOfParent` or `/newtopic.jsp?id=valueOfParent` (without %3F)

Comment: no.. it still doesn't work; only with /newtopic.jsp?id=valueOfParent

Comment: The `%3F` is URL-encoded representation of `?` which suggests that you were *actually* using `<f:param name="?id">` instead of `<f:param name="id">`. I have no idea why you're doing like that; the answer of Daniel doesn't show at all that you need to do that.